# How to edit subject in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I have checked on this site and found the subject on how to edit subject in Gmail. When I click on the more button next to reply tick, then click on reply in the list offered, it does not show an edit subject as suggested in the answers already given. I merely get sent to the area to compose my reply.

As I have done everything as suggested, please can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

You don't seem to have gone far enough... once you are in the compose area, click on the dropdown menu to the left of the "To:" field, you then get the option to "Edit Subject".

[image: Edit Subject menu item]

Editing the subject has the additional side effect of "popping out" the reply.

Answer (score 2):

1. Click **Reply**
2. Click on the arrow at the left of the *To* field
3. Click **Edit subject**

[image]